# Authorization link broken when migrating from Blogger to Wordpress

Tags: migration, blogger

I recently purchased a domain and hosting and I'm running a WordPress site on a subdomain.  I want to transfer a small blog of mine which is hosted on Blogger.  I've seen instructions [such as these](https://rtcamp.com/blogger-to-wordpress/tutorials/permalink-seo-migration/) that walk you through the steps, but when I get to this page:

[image: Authorization page]

The <kbd>Authorize</kbd> link leads me a [broken Google support page](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6224347?p=oauth&rd=1) that looks like this:

[image]

Does this mean that automatic migration from Blogger to WordPress is no longer supported?  Does this link simply need to be updated?  Are there other options I should consider to transfer my blog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin is obsolete as of August 2015.  According to [this thread](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/obsolete-plugin-3?replies=2), a new version is being worked on.  Until then, I have found success importing Blogger using [this alternative plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/view/plugin-reviews/blogger-importer-extended).